# Live streaming through mediaplayer in android

Tags: android, media-player, http-live-streaming

How can I stream an online URL using MediaPlayer?

Comment: "i tried such a long but same result" - what result?

Comment: please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Lalit u can see what i tried on this below heading on stack overflow...


Android http live Streaming URL using mediaplayer

Comment: Getting errors like Mediaplayer error(1,-1002), start state is 0 and error(-38, 0) why.?

Comment: If you're using http live streaming (HLS/pantos-http-live-streaming-07), it's only supported in Android 3.0 and higher.

You can see google's release notes here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html

You need to provide more information in your question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you need to do the following if you are using the Android MediaPlayer class:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        mp.reset();
        return false;
    }
});

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});

try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://someurl");
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Keep in mind the Android MediaPlayer class will only play supported formats:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: hi, native media player is supports adaptive bitrate streaming or not?

Answer (score 3):

Working for me in API 28

```
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://209.188.21.202:8016/stream");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
```

Please Remember to add permissions to manifest if using INTERNET

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also careful with usesCleartextTraffic

Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

In my case I add --> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest

Reference -->

[Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("YOUR URL HERE"));
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: @ NAVdroid i used this also but its showing not sending buffering status because duration is unknown...plz give me suggestion if u have done before....

Comment: mediaplayer start called in state 2

Answer (score 0):

The MediaPlayer  is buggy if you are streaming audio from remote URL. It works sometimes but hangs mostly for remote.

Have tried below which hangs

```
   mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("YOUR URL HERE"));
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

also tried
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); and implement onprepared listener. Doesnt work.. Device used is Samsung galaxy mini

Have been trying to read the URL content manually and update the MediaPlayer datasource with the buffered content. Works moslty, but yet to figure out how to switch URLs etc..

The example here is for VideoPlayer but should be same concept for audio player as well

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

### Edit

Ah just found this http://launch-code.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/android-play-audio-asyncplayer.html
Seems to wrap the calls to MediaPlayer nicely : http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AsyncPlayer.java

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String vidAddress ="your http link";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        vidView.start();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```