# Android Media Player HLS

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to run HLS on Android media player. I am using the code provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8178040).
The sample video URL runs but when I replace link with hls [link](http://mn-i.mncdn.com/mekameleen_ios/live2/playlist.m3u8) it doesn't work.

Logcat output:

```
GPU monitor inactive - could not find libgpumonitor.so [(null)] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.gpumonitor = 0)
```

Comment: for playing live streaming u must have the media extension like .mp3,etc i.e the formats which android supports. Its impossible as far as concern.

Comment: if u r using FFMPEG then it might be possible. But its a tedious job.

Comment: As today (June 2019) Android MediaPlayer can play HLS URL.
The URL you have posted simply returns 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Android media player does not support HLS playback. The NuPlayer (in 5.1.1) although streams HLS content, but the frame rendering is not as smooth as MP4 rendering.